# Difference between minCompileSdk and compileSdk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, androidx

Looking at this [release note](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.6.0-alpha05) for AppCompat, there is now a `minCompileSdk` I wonder what is the difference of this from `compileSdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Gradle API's AAR documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/variant/AarMetadata#mincompilesdk):

> `minCompileSdk`: Minimum `compileSdkVersion` needed to consume this library. This is the minimum sdk version a module must use in order to import this library.

So a library can embed what SDK version it requires in order to work. For example, if AppCompat depends on API 33 APIs, your app must also compile with API 33 to work (otherwise those APIs that AppCompat is attempting to use don't exist when compiling your app, which would cause AGP and ProGuard to fail).

Therefore there aren't just differences - they're two entirely different sides of the same coin. `minCompileSdk` is something a library enforces on apps, while `compileSdkVersion` is something your app sets itself.

Comment: Thanks Ian, so is it necessary to use `minCompileSdk` for this case? If yes then should I replace `compileSdkVersion` with it or add it inside `android` or `defaultConfig`?

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer. `minCompileSdk` is never, ever, ever something you'll ever put in your app or in any of your `build.gradle` files. It is something a library includes in their AAR. The only implication for you app is that you'll get an error if your `compileSdkVersion` is lower than the library you are using requires (which just means you need to update your `compileSdkVersion`) rather than your app just failing randomly.

Comment: oohh shoot, yes it is in the last paragraph thanks